# How to save gensim LDA topics output to csv along with the scores?

Tags: python-2.7, gensim

How to save the output? I am using the following code:

```
%time lda1 = models.LdaModel(corpus1, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary1, update_every=5, chunksize=10000, passes=100)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To export topic mixtures of each document to a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

mixture = [dict(lda_model[x]) for x in corpus1]
pd.DataFrame(mixture).to_csv("topic_mixture.csv")
```

To export the top words for each topic to a csv file:

```
top_words_per_topic = []
for t in range(lda_model.num_topics):
    top_words_per_topic.extend([(t, ) + x for x in lda_model.show_topic(t, topn = 5)])

pd.DataFrame(top_words_per_topic, columns=['Topic', 'Word', 'P']).to_csv("top_words.csv")
```

The CSV file will have the following format

```
Topic Word  P  
0     w1    0.004437  
0     w2    0.003553  
0     w3    0.002953  
0     w4    0.002866  
0     w5    0.008813  
1     w6    0.003393  
1     w7    0.003289  
1     w8    0.003197 
...
```

Comment: great, this works! anyway i can get the labels of the topics instead of topic 0-19?

Comment: The LDA model itself does not come with labeling as its training result. Gensim can only print out top words in a topic.

Comment: yes, thanks feng! actually i meant to ask - is there a way to store the top words and their coeffs (or scores) in csv / text format?

Comment: @VP10 did you get the method for storing top words and their coefficients ? i am also working on this but i don't know how to store them in csv